# Laravel not send the broadcast event to pusher console

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I followed the instruction from this link to create a web push using pusher: https://blog.pusher.com/create-web-notifications-using-laravel-pusher/

But when i tried to fire my event, i cant see any event catch in my pusher dashboard debug console.

Here is the screenshot of my test

[image: Image preview]

Here are some code

route/web.php :

```
Route::get('/eventtest', function () {
    event(new App\Events\StatusChanged('someone'));
    return "Event has been sent!";
});
```

event class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class StatusChanged implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return new PrivateChannel('statusChanged');
        return ['status-changed'];
    }
}
```

broadcasting config :

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'ap1',
                'encrypted' => true
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Have you specified pusher as broadcast driver in your .env file? If yes, then check the region of your app cluster in pusher matches to 'ap1'

Comment: @PawanKumar i already set the env file and my app cluster is set to ap1 while i created it

Comment: Okay, did you uncomment   ````App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,```` in ````config/app.php```` ?

Comment: @PawanKumar yup, i already uncommented it.

Comment: Okay, Please check your App cluster region. Try creating an App in EU region and see if it works. Also change the cluster to ````'eu'```` in ````broadcast.php````.

Comment: @PawanKumar i tried in EU and US but it still doesnt work